# I am facing an issue with Jenkins.I selected Execute windows batch command in Jenkins and getting below error

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I am using robot framework for UI testing and i created one .bat file and i am passing that into Jenkins. When i build the project i am getting below error.

[Windows image for batch job command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMD8u.png)

[Jenkins output error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKcTK.png)

[Execute shell error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3REhe.png)

Comment: Don't use images to show code and errors. Please paste the code inside blockquotes (``````error here``````)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have Jenkins Master hosted on a Linux machine and you are running windows batch command on the master. If you want to run windows batch command on master, please add a windows slave machine and run your job on that machine. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Actually in my scenario developers are working in Linux machine. Here we can't add windows slave into the Jenkins. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: I didn't understand the scenario still, do u want to execute certain scripts on the Linux Jenkins master machine? -  if so you can use Execute Shell instead of Execute windows batch command. But you have to use linux shell command. If you want to execute certain windows commands on a windows machine, add a windows machine as a slave and then use the Execcute Windows batch command.

Comment: Yes, I m executing in Linux master and We don't have access to install windows slave in Jenkins. I tried using Execute shell with robot file. This time i am getting "command robot not found" error and i tried with direct batch file as well, Still same issue. Please find the attached screenshot for your reference.

Comment: You cannot execute batch files in Linux. You have to use Shell scripts (.sh). By the way, is robot framework an install-able script or is it checked out from any source control. If its the later, is it an .exe file. If so, it is not compatible with Linux. Install Robot framework on the Linux master.

Comment: Thanks .. I installed all the required packages in linux machine . it is working fine